# Uploading multiple Folders to the Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I am writing a Powershell script to upload multiple folders and sub folders to the AWS S3 bucket, it is giving the below error. I recreated the same for uploading a single folder and the error remains the same. But when i try to upload files using the -File parameter it is working fine. Could someone help me out here.

```
Write-S3Object -BucketName my-bucket -Folder "D:\Testfolder" -Key "****/****" -Recurse 
      -Credential $AWSCreds -Region us-east-1.
```

---

```
Write-S3Object : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Write-S3Object -BucketName teamsite-s3 -Folder "D:\Testfolder\" -Key  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-S3Object], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.S3.WriteS3ObjectCmdlet
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed by using the parameter `-Keyprefix` instead of `-Key`

This Did not work

```
Write-S3Object -BucketName my-bucket -Folder "D:\Testfolder" -Key "****/****" -Recurse     -Credential $AWSCreds -Region us-east-1.
```

This Works

```
Write-S3Object -BucketName my-bucket -Folder "D:\Testfolder" -Keyprefix "****/****" -Recurse -Credential $AWSCreds -Region us-east-1.
```